# What's necessary to properly decouple/filter a PWM-controlled fan from an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, power, noise, fan

I've got a small problem I could use some help with. I am using an Arduino to control a cooling system I am building for a DSLR. Primary goals are to use PWM and some pots to control TEC power, as well as fan power. There will likely be two TECs and two fans, both attached to a long 98mmx40mm heatsink. Another goal is to keep the whole cooler unit as simple as possible, so I would like to use a single power connection, and preferably a standard connection (i.e. 5.5mmx2.5mm power jack if at all possible) that is frequently used with astrophotography gear.

The problem is that if I power the fans off the same +12V as the Arduino, could the fans inject a lot of noise onto the power lines? I have done some electronics tinkering, but I've rarely used motors, so I don't know a lot.

I do know that I need a diode (I plan to use Schottky diodes, since the fans will be controlled via PWM) across the positive an negative leads to the fans in order to avoid voltage spikes when power to the fans is cut off.

I also have read that a small capacitor parallel to the diode and fan can also be used to filter the noise a bit. It sounds like the capacitor should be QUITE small...anywhere from 100pF to 10nF? I don't know if there is an easy way to determine what size capacitor should be used. I am also not sure if a simple small capacitor like that would be sufficient to filter the noise generated by the fans, especially when using an Arduino.

I know that an opto-isolator (or opto-coupler) could be used instead of a MOSFET with the PWM signal to totally isolate the fan power circuit from the Arduino. I believe that would require using a totally independent power connection for the fans, though. That goes against my design goals of standardized simplicity. So, I am wondering if there is another way to isolate the fans from the Arduino enough that an opto-isolator would work well enough. If that is not possible, would using an LC or LRC filter on the fans be enough to filter out the noise and protect the Arduino?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to control the speed of the fans? Why not run them at full-speed all the time? Then you could use a simple relay/SSR/MOSFET and even a different power source if you're worried about noise.  Another test is to simply grab your oscilloscope and watch for noise on the power rails when running the fans.

Comment: Check out this article on motor capacitors: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/267/why-are-capacitors-added-to-motors-in-parallel-what-is-their-purpose

Comment: I wish I had an oscilloscope. :P I tinker, but there are long spells between tinkering. I've never done it consistently enough where I thought I could justify an oscilloscope. The cheapest ones (and I never like to buy "cheapest") seem to be around a $100, decent ones seem to be a few hundred at least, and very good ones easily seem to top $1000.

Comment: One of my goals is to power this cooler with a single power connection. I don't know of any way of supplying the fans with a different power source without having two power connections, and I would really like to avoid that. Leaving the fans on full power is probably an option...but couldn't they still introduce noise into the system regardless?

Comment: Is motor noise as much of a problem if the motor being used is brushless? It sounds like a lot of the noise problems have to do with brushed motors, sparking, and radio frequency emissions. With a brushless motor, there wouldn't be any sparking...I assume there would still be some problems with noise, but the fans I am going to be using are pretty low power (12V 100mA tops, likely as little as 65mA) and definitely brushless...

Comment: Yes I think there would still be noise, but I think that's the purpose of some fairly large caps across your +V/neutral rails directly from your power supply.  I'm sure the power supply has some of these caps inside too.  As an example, computers use the same power supply to drive both the fans and the digital circuitry.  They are connected to the same rails internally.  Unless your PSU is too weak to source the appropriate current for everything, I think you will be fine.

Comment: I will be using a large G29 deep cycle DC battery, so it won't have any built-in capacitors. I can put some caps on the power lines, though. Any idea how to calculate how large those caps should be?

Comment: Here's a page about DC PSU design showing the implementation of smoothing caps: http://www.skillbank.co.uk/psu/smoothing.htm.  Looks like you would need to know the frequency of the ripple you're trying to attenuate (probably some multiple of fan RPM) and the P-P voltage of that ripple.  If I'm not mistaken, using a battery as the supply acts as a stabilizer (think *huge* capacitor) also.  I have a feeling there won't be a problem even if you omit the caps.  You could probably leave them off and only add if you notice issues with the digital electronics randomly restarting etc.